# How to show values of a instance with line break in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console, pry

I start to using `pry` in a rails console.
When I get a instance of a Rails model, the values are shown without line breaks like this:

```
pry(#<Class:0x1022f60e0>):1> first
=> #<Article id: 1, name: "What is Music", content: "Music is an art form in which the medium is sound o...", created_at: "2011-08-24 20:35:29", updated_at: "2011-08-24 20:37:22", published_at: "2011-05-13 23:00:00">
```

from http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?view=asciicast

Is there way to show the values with line breaks like this?

```
Article
 id: 1
 name: "What is Music"
 content: "Music is an art form in which the medium is sound o..."
 created_at: "2011-08-24 20:35:29"
 updated_at: "2011-08-24 20:37:22"
 published_at: "2011-05-13 23:00:00"
```

Comment: Have you tried `.to_yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call .to_yaml on the model instance! It returns a string that's formatted almost exactly like you're requesting it to be.

Here are some examples of to_yaml output:

http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/examples.htm

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you install [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print).

Add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'awesome_print'
end
```

And install it with `bundle install`.

Now use `ap` to print it in the console:

```
pry(#<Class:0x1022f60e0>):1> ap first

#<Article:0x1022f60e0> {
           :id => 1,
         :name => "What is Music"
      :content => "Music is an art form in which the medium is sound o..."
   :created_at => "2011-08-24 20:35:29"
   :updated_at => "2011-08-24 20:37:22"
 :published_at => "2011-05-13 23:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the below *trick* will work for you.

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Rails/model_prac> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.1.2 :001 > Comment.first
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"   ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Comment id: 1, value_old: "I am a good Boy.", value_new: "I am a bad Boy.", created_at: "2014-08-02 17:36:14", updated_at: "2014-08-02 18:21:42">
2.1.2 :002 > y Comment.first
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"   ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
--- !ruby/object:Comment
attributes:
  id: 1
  value_old: I am a good Boy.
  value_new: I am a bad Boy.
  created_at: 2014-08-02 17:36:14.249466000 Z
  updated_at: 2014-08-02 18:21:42.511522000 Z
 => nil
2.1.2 :003 >
```